# Why is my Mulberry bush flowering later than all my other trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, shrubs, mulberry

I have a Mulberry bush in my garden that I planted last year. I can see buds on it like the leaves are starting to grow.  The thing is every other tree in my garden has flowers now, even my apple tree.

Why is my Mulberry bush so far behind everything else?

Answer (score 2):

How old is it and what size is it?  It is possible that it's just not large enough to flower yet.  Most trees (and mulberry is generally considered a tree, although dwarf varieties are available) take at least 3-5 years to begin to flower and set fruit.  If it's a small plant still and you just transplanted it last year, it would not be surprising at all if doesn't fruit this year.

Also, not all trees flower first and then leaf out.  Some leaf out and flower at the same time, and some leaf out first and then flower.  Mulberries, if I recall correctly, generally bloom around the same time their leaves begin to grow out of the bud.  So it may still be early yet to judge whether it is going to flower this year or not.

Comment: There were berries on it when I bought it. I would guess that it is 4 feet tall. The stem is a little more than an inch thick.  It wasn't small i couldn't lift the pot it was in alone.

Comment: Okay, if you know it's already fruited, then maybe it's still just a bit early?  If you don't see any flower buds soon, then let us know and we can try to help you troubleshoot the problem.  It would help to know what conditions it's growing in - for example, is it in full sun?  Shade?  Wet soil, dry soil, etc.

Comment: I just checked it today and it has leafs on it.  So i guess it is coming its just going to be slower then everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I've just checked where you are - as you're in a northerly climate, mulberry should be planted in the sunniest, most sheltered spot available, preferably in front of a wall which faces south, which will give it optimum conditions. It may be that you've had late frosts and that's why the mulberry has been reluctant to put on growth - hopefully, you dug over the area prior to planting and incorporated plenty of humus rich material such as garden compost, and you have kept it well watered during drier spells.

UPDATE: Thanks to more research for another question, I've finally found the info I was looking for - I had an idea that Morus comes into leaf later than other fruiting trees, and it does, so it will/should be later than your other fruiting trees.